# Unity - Network manager not working properly outside Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I'm making a game in Unity, I want to instantiate the network manager at a certain screen, so I use a prefab for the network manager, my code is as follows:-

```
void Start()
{
    Transform cloneNetworkManager = Instantiate(networkManager, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    NetworkManagerScript networkManagerScript = cloneNetworkManager.GetComponent<NetworkManagerScript>();
    networkManagerScript.OnButtonHost();
    ip = Network.player.ipAddress;
}
```

and the code for the network manager is as follows:-

```
public class NetworkManagerScript : NetworkManager {
    public GameObject player;

    public void OnButtonHost()
    {
        networkPort = 10101;
        playerPrefab = player;
        StartHost();
    }

    public void OnButtonClient()
    {
        JoinMultiplayerScreenScript joinMultiplayerScreenScript = FindObjectOfType<JoinMultiplayerScreenScript>();
        networkAddress = joinMultiplayerScreenScript.ip.text;
        networkPort = 10101;
        playerPrefab = player;
        StartClient();
    }
}
```

The problem now is when I run the project inside the Unity editor it runs correctly, displays the ip, and creates a player.

[image: like this image]

But when I deploy the project to a windows application or Android application it doesn't display the ip or create a player.

[image: like this image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

I discovered that I was deploying another scene.

I'm very sorry